# Buffer caache usage for symbolic link

Tags: linux

on linux when we create a symbolic link to a different file then an inode is used to store the filepath to the original file. So in this context if we create a symbolic link towards a large size file which is already in buffer cache then reading from symbolic link will find the file in buffer cache or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes when the file is opened it will resolve the symlink and open the file it points to.